# How to sort objects by value

Tags: javascript

Say you have the following object in JS:

```
let obj = {a: 24, b: 12, c:21; d:15};
```

How can 'obj' be transformed into an array of the keys of the object, sorted by the values?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```js
let obj = {a: 24, b: 12, c:21, d:15};

// Get an array of the keys:
let keys = Object.keys(obj);

// Then sort by using the keys to lookup the values in the original object:
keys.sort((a, b) => obj[a] - obj[b]);

console.log(keys);
```

Note that the above could be done in one line if desired with `Object.keys(obj).sort(...)`. The simple [`.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort?v=control) comparator function shown will only work for numeric values. Swap `a` and `b` to sort in the opposite direction.

Comment: This only works for numeric values, so if your array has other types, you'll have to define the full `compareFunction`.

Comment: Does `Object.keys()` return an array?

Comment: Yes, `Object.keys()` returns an array. You can do the above in one line if desired, as `Object.keys(obj).sort(...)`. @Blender - Yes, but it doesn't. We can't really define a generic sort comparator to cater to all types, because the values could be nested objects or...anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
var obj  = {
  a: 24, b: 12, c:21, d:15
};
var sortable = [];
for (var x in obj ) {
    sortable.push([x, obj[x]]);
}

sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
});

console.log(sortable)
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the way to get sort the object and get sorted object in return

```
let sortedObject = {}
sortedObject = Object.keys(yourObject).sort((a, b) => {
                        return yourObject[a] - yourObject[b] 
                    }).reduce((prev, curr, i) => {
                        prev[i] = yourObject[curr]
                        return prev
                    }, {});
```

> you can customise your sorting function as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

Wrapped in a function with ASC or DESC.

```js
const myobj = {a: 24, b: 12, c:21, d:15};

function sortObjectbyValue(obj={},asc=true){ 
   const ret = {};
   Object.keys(obj).sort((a,b) => obj[asc?a:b]-obj[asc?b:a]).forEach(s => ret[s] = obj[s]);
   return ret
}

console.log(sortObjectbyValue(myobj))
```

Answer (score -1):

If the purpose is just monitoring the sorted object in console, I suggest log the object in console with `console.table(obj)` instead of `console.log(obj)` and the result will be sortable for both key and value, asc and desc in fastest way with no extra process.
[image]